# How do I open the content from an html page into a dialog from another html page with href using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsp

I'm trying to get the content from an html page to load into a jQuery ui dialog box when the user clicks on the main html page.  However, while this seemed simple, it's not working.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#modal' ).dialog({ modal : true });

$(function() {
     $('a[name=Test]').on('click', function(e){
     $('#modal').load(this.href).dialog('open');
  });
});
</script>
</head>
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <p><a name="Test" href="test/test2.html">Click Here!</a></p>
</body>
```

Once I get this working, I'll move it to jsp's with the real code, but I'm trying to get it working standalone first.

I've seen other examples, but I haven't been able to get this to fire up the dialog with the content.  It only redirects me to the test2.html page.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors in browser console related to this `dialog`?

Comment: can you attach an id to the a tag and use that as the selector? <a name="Test" id="test" href="test/test2.html">Click Here!</a> then use $('#test').on('event', 'function(){...}')

Comment: I don't see any errors in the firebug console.  That was the first thing I checked.  I tried using an id on the anchor tag, but I didn't see any difference.  I can try that again.

Comment: Is the on click event firing? Try add an alert in the click event handler

Comment: Yes, I put an alert in and it fires.  'a['#Test']'... or 'a[#Test]' gives me a console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<p><a name="Test" href="test/test2.html">Click Here!</a></p>

<div id="modal"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
     $('a[name=Test]').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault(); //stops from going to test2.html
         $('#modal').load(this.href).dialog({ modal : true });
  });
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/becLJ/

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one! I had similar snippets of code, but couldn't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="Scripts/Global/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Global/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script>
            function openDialog() {
                (function () {
                    $('#dialog').dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        draggable: false,
                        width: '1100',
                        height: '900',
                        title: 'Sample Dialog'
                    });
                })();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dialog" style="display:none;"><iframe style="width:98%;height:98%;" id="modalDialogBox" src="dialogPage.htm"></iframe></div>
        <a onclick="openDialog()">Click Me</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I don't like using iFrames for solutions.  Only as a last resort.

Comment: No problem, glad you found the answer you needed anyway.